# Android app crashes: cause not clear

Tags: android, crash, out-of-memory

When running my app in whatever type of simulator I get the following stacktrace but do not understand what the error could be:

```
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at de.derwettprofi.matchView.MatchViewAdapter.getView(MatchViewAdapter.java:78)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1638)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     ... 47 more
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
08-04 22:35:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     ... 50 more
```

What is wrong with my app?

Comment: Have you tried closing your project, and your emulator?

Comment: Use MAT to diagnose memory leaks and other out-of-memory causes: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: Add the relevant parts of your code to your question, namely the getView method of your MatchViewAdapter.

Comment: This looks like OOM due to loading an image. what is the size of the image you are trying to load?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this errors is a consequence of too large image size. However, I think the size is quite okay (png 130kb). Sometimes it crashes and other time it does not. On my physical device the app runs without any problems. So how could this be solved?